# Using C# summary documentation as tooltip in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, documentation

In unity, I often end up with duplicating the  tags for code documentation, and the [tooltip] tags for the Unity Inspector.

Is there a way to automatically extract  tags into Unity [tooltip]s, or vice versa?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This field sets the whirlygigs speed.
    /// </summary>
    [Tooltip("This field sets the whirlygigs speed.")]
    public float value;
```

Comment: I would try the opposite approach: Get your documentation generation tool to detect and extract Unity Tooltip annotations.

Comment: Good point, a solution could go either way.  Am currently trying to get something going by querying the XMLDocumentation (https://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=49) using a Unity CustomPropertyDrawer.

Comment: Hi @Jethro - did you ever find a working solution to this? I'm looking for the exact same. It's especially frustrating when there are [many attributes](https://hastebin.com/yudagecufe.cs) existing for a variable.

Comment: @Bejasc Sorry, I never found a solution.

Comment: No worries, this would be a super handy thing to have. Cheers for the quick response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin in the asset store doing the exact same:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/comment-to-tooltip-120659#description